# Flask login for REST APIs

Tags: rest, authentication, flask, flask-login, flask-restful

I am implementing REST APIs using Flask Restful and want to add session based auth for users. Currently I am NOT implementing a web app. I am wondering if the Flask-Login extension can only be used for web apps or can I use them for my REST application too?

Answer (score 0):

Altough a RESTful service should be stateless by definition,

I would avoid that one. It's more "form-oriented".

Go for OAuth2, it's the de facto standard for RESTful web services.

A good implementation is **Flask-OAuthlib**, available on GitHub.